# Are routers necessary in a 2-tier LAN design?

Tags: design

I am learning about various network topologies/design and I often see the following topology as an example for a 2-tier design.

[image]

Why are the layer 3 switches at the distribution layer connected to routers? Couldn't they simply directly connect to the internet without the routers in the path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've never used a "layer-3 switch"? They are switches first, and router a distant third. Their routing capabilities are exceptionally limited. They're usually fine for inter-vlan routing within an enterprise, but on the internet edge, they lack NAT, firewall capabilities (best left to a dedicated FW), tunneling / VPN, more complex routing protocols, etc. While there are switches that support many of these features, they are a switch first, their ability to do anything else is hamstrung by that.

For example, my few old Cisco Nexus switches are some of the "big iron" in the L3-switch world, but the merchant silicon (broadcom) does not support NAT, so *feature nat* cannot be enabled. When I set one up to handle IPv6 routing -- and tunneling -- I had to manually tune how TCAM was divided... finite number of L3 interfaces, finite number of routes (v4 and v6), finite number of ACL rules... all subtracted from it's switching capabilities. The much older Cisco 2960S's lose almost half their switch capabilities (MAC tables) to enable "lan-lite" routing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need routers for the 2-tiered LAN itself but if you connect it to *other* networks you do require a router - or two for redundancy.

Without routers routing between networks, you cannot connect them.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But couldn't those two L3 switches at the distribution layer simply perform the routing? Without being connected to actual routers. If there are 2 switches like in the topology I posted, that are capable of routing,, is it necessary to then connect them to routers?

Comment: Hypothetically yes - however, core routers and WAN routers often require different feature sets and can't be combined easily. With IPv4, NAT is a requirement for WAN connectivity and usually absent in the core. Also, WAN connections require a firewall that may be included in the routers but aren't present in core routers.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to understand the difference between a "router" and "routing".  Also, a "switch" and "switching".

"Routing" is what you call it when you forward packets using layer-3 information.  "Switching" is what you call it when you forward frames using layer-2 information.  There exist "routers" that can perform "switching", and there exist "switches" that can perform "routing".

The main benefit of a "router" is that they typically have lots of memory to hold large routing tables (sometimes multiple gigabytes of tables) and they use the CPU to perform things like VPN tunnels and NAT, and they accept additional media types beside Ethernet.  The benefit of a "switch" is that it performs most of its actions using hardware chips, rather than the general-purpose CPU.  Historically, switches have been able to switch faster than routers have been able to route.  In the last 5 to 10 years, that difference has vanished since there now exist widely-available hardware chips that can route (and perform other stuff, too, like encapsulation).

It is possible to use a switch as an internet router.  And if you do it right, it can be secure.  But, that's not what switches were designed to do.  Just like you can use a Vise-grip to hammer in a nail, but that's not what it was invented for.